# Moving average and displacement

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

1. I am using a moving average = 100 in pine script
2. Another moving average 100 with displacement (offset) 20.

Required:

i.e.

```
myMAVal = 100
plot(myMAVal)
plot(myMAVal, offset=20) // how to capture or store the value with offset of 20
```

Now I want to use `crossover()` and `crossunder()` in pine code.

`myMAVal` is 100, but `myMAVal + offset` .... is wrong, it will not cross it will be 120 another moving average with 120

i.e the plotted 100 with offset crossover or crossunder is required

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the issue correctly, you want to do a crossover of a Moving Average with an offset of the same.

In that case, you should be applying the offset to the moving average, not the plot, by using a subscript operator `[]`.

Below is the code:

```
myMAVal = 100
MA_offset = 20

ma1 = ta.sma(close, myMAVal)
ma2 = ma1[MA_offset]

plot(ma1)
plot(ma2)
```

Now you can do further calculations on `ma1` and `ma2`.